# I am looking for a method to estimate a threshold function for binary outcome data

Tags: inference, econometrics, estimators

A literature search yielded no obvious answers, so I wonder here if there any feasible methods to estimate the following.

Suppose I have data $Y_i, \vec X_i$ indexed by $i = 1, \cdots, N$.
Note that $Y_i$ represents a scalar binary outcome, and $\vec X_i$ a vector of predictors.

I assume that my data are generated by the following, where $\mathbf{1}\left\{ . \right\}$ is the indicator function, $\varepsilon_i$ independent error, and $f(.)$ an unknown function,
$$ Y_i = \mathbf{1}\left\{ f(\vec X_i) \geq 0 \right\} + \varepsilon_i $$

Are there any methods to estimate the function, $f(.)$, or more likely  moment of the function $E[f(X_i)]$, possibly non-parametrically?

Comment: Are you saying that the outcome is completely deterministic? Or is it a random Bernoulli variable and the success probability varies according to a linear combination of the variables?

Comment: This question is correct to ask, I meant to say that there is random error, $\varepsilon_i$, in the DGP.

And yes, I guess it is basically the same problem as estimating Bernoulli success probability with a combination of the variables.
This means I can use an MLE approach with predictors $\vec X_i$ for a Bernoulli success probability.

Comment: I'm not sure what "DGP" is, but if you treat $Y$ as Bernoulli, then there's no need to invoke an error term. If you set each $Y_i$ as a Bernoulli($p_i$) random variable, you can model the (logit) $p_i$ as a linear combination of $\vec{X}_i$ using **logistic regression**. This is probably the answer to your problem.